# How to restore a canceled Task

Tags: date, date-format, processmaker

How to restore a canceled Task

hi
How can to restore a canceled task?
Is it possible return canceld task to TO_DO?
i work with data base and tables( APPLICATION,APP_DELEGATION,SUB_APPLICATION,APP_THREAD)
and could return a canceled task to TO_DO but does not run only be shown in the list TO_DO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[process maker forum](http://forum.processmaker.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=706940)

You have to modify the following tables by looking for your case number:

APPLICATION

- APP_STATUS change to TO_DO

APP_DELEGATION

- DEL_THREAD_STATUS change to OPEN
- DEL_FINISH_DATE change to NULL

APP_THREAD

- APP_THREAD_STATUS change to OPEN

Then your case will be on your inbox without executing any derivation.